# How can I divide a text row in a data frame into several rows, but still have the new rows connected to the same ID (Python)?

Tags: python, dataframe, text-processing

I have a meeting minutes data set. I have made a dataframe, and I would like to split the text, which is a speech, and each speech has several paragraphs. The length of each speech varies from speech to speech. I want the text data to be divided into paragraphs so I can analyze each paragraph instead of the whole speech. However, I want the text unit (paragraph) to keep the document id, and get a new text unit id. The text unit id would refer to number of paragraph in the speech.

This is how it looks like now:

| row number | text_unit_id | doc_id | text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3000_speech_1 | Bla bla bla (new line) Bla bla bla (new line) Bla bla bla |
| 2 | 1 | 3000_speech_2 | Bla bla bla (new line) Bla bla bla |

I want to be like this:

| row_number | text_unit_id | doc_id | text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3000_speech_1 | Bla bla bla |
| 2 | 2 | 3000_speech_1 | Bla bla bla |
| 3 | 3 | 3000_speech_1 | Bla bla bla |
| 4 | 1 | 3000_speech_2 | Bla bla bla |
| 5 | 2 | 3000_speech_2 | Bla bla bla |

Answer (score 0):

You can split the lines using `.str.split("\n")`, then massage the DataFrame a bit using [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html), and finally [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) the lines and the initial DataFrame to keep your metadata, maybe like:

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {
            "doc_id": "3000_speech_1",
            "text": "Speech 1 head\nSpeech 1 body\nSpeech 1 tail",
        },
        {
            "doc_id": "3000_speech_2",
            "text": "Speech 2 head\nSpeech 2 tail",
        },
    ]
)

print(df)

lines = (
    df.text.str.split("\n")
    .apply(pd.Series)
    .melt(ignore_index=False, value_name="line", var_name="text_unit_id")
    .dropna()
)

del df["text"]
print(df.merge(lines, left_index=True, right_index=True))
```

Which transforms:

```
          doc_id                                         text
0  3000_speech_1  Speech 1 head\nSpeech 1 body\nSpeech 1 tail
1  3000_speech_2                 Speech 2 head\nSpeech 2 tail
```

to

```
          doc_id  text_unit_id           line
0  3000_speech_1             0  Speech 1 head
0  3000_speech_1             1  Speech 1 body
0  3000_speech_1             2  Speech 1 tail
1  3000_speech_2             0  Speech 2 head
1  3000_speech_2             1  Speech 2 tail
```

Comment: Thank you! Haven't manged to fix it yet, but this helps :-) I got a TypeError for melt function. I typed this; pd.melt(df_copy, ignore_index=False, var_name="text_unit_id", value_name="line"), and the error was TypeError: melt() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ignore_index'.  Do you know why this happens?

Comment: ignore_index is new since pandas==1.1.0 from 2020-07-28, so please `python3 -m pip install pandas>=1.1.0`.